# Using php variable in a block of code implemented with jquery before()

Tags: php, jquery

I already asked this question and it has been marked as duplicate by the first person who came and thought that I asked how to find the current url using javascript. **This is not my question !**

I'm wondering if this is possible, right now I can't seem to be able to make it work but I would be glad to hear it can work.

So first, I have this random page in which I pasted a script tag to load my js file, and a php variable getting my current url :

```
<script src="/plugin-cookies/front-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php $currentlink = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Then, in my js file I have a jquery function to append the wanted files to the page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("cookies-include.php", function(data){
    $('footer').last().before(data);
});
$.get("cookies-margin.php", function(data){
    $('head').append(data);
});
});
```

Finally, in my "cookies-include.php" file, I want to use this "$currentlink" variable (I can't set it in cookies-include.php because it gives me the link to itself...).

Here is th code I want to use in cookies-include.php (which is implemented in the page via jquery) :

```
global $currentlink;
if($currentlink == $setlink){
    do stuff...
} else {
    some other stuff...
}
```

I tried to "echo" $currentlink but I don't get anything.

What I don't get is that the $currentlink variable is set before the js function starts, so shouldn't it be fine ?

So to sum it up :

1 - I create my php variable and call my js file in a page

2 - My js file implements a second php file inside the page using before()

3 - I want the php file that I implemented in the page to use the variable that was created in the first point.

Comment: Could you explain why you are doing this?

Comment: I'm trying to make a plugin that I could install the easiest and fastest way on old websites : The thing is I don't want to have to paste more than two lines of code in the header and the plugin folder in the ftp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `$currentlink` to javascript variable and pass it as argument to `cookies-include.php` in the ajax call

Something like

```
<script src="/plugin-cookies/front-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var currentlink = 'http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("cookies-include.php?currentlink="+currentlink, function(data){
        $('footer').last().before(data);
    });
    $.get("cookies-margin.php?currentlink="+currentlink, function(data){
        $('head').append(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

In PHP

```
$currentlink = $_GET['currentlink'];
if($currentlink == $setlink){
    do stuff...
} else {
    some other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Your idea worked great! I used it with a different syntax but it's the same thing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentlink = $('#currentlink').val();
$.post("cookies-include.php", {"currentlink": currentlink}).done(function(data){
    $('footer').last().before(data);
});
});
```

Juste note that I modified the $currentlink variable in my page to be a hidden input in order to get its value with js :

```
<input type ="hidden" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="currentlink" name="currentlink"/>
```